# Making a diff on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can I do a diff between two databases on SQL Server 2005, without a third-party software? Only sqlcmd or SQL Management Studio.

The diff  must be only on the structure: tables, store procedures (usp), views, etc.

Thanks.

Note: No, I **can not** install anything, is for stage environment.

Comment: I think there is a two-part issue here. One is extract the schema and the other is generating a schema-diff. SMO could be used to extract the schema (e.g. using PowerShell) in an easily repeatable way. However, to compare the schema -- for anything except the most trivial "what is different?" cases -- I would really consider picking up a Schema Diff tool (and running it *in a dev environment* on the extract schema). Most Schema Diff tools are very un-programmer friendly and require "real databases", but some can work just on scripts. (For a price > $0.) Also, *perhaps try the DBA stack*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `All Tasks -> Generate Script`, and save the result for the two servers in a different file.

Now you can use standard diff tools like [windiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff) to compare the two.  Because you're comparing files on your workstation, you do not have to install anything on the DB servers.

Comment: Unfortunately this is ... very time consuming. There are third-party solutions that can take "scripts" and use them to generate proper schema-diffs. Granted, this is done for a fee. (I have not found similar functionality on a Open Source/free product, excluding manually importing to a live DB first.) Also, "Generate Script" takes a bunch of [everytime] clicking to get it to be "just right" :-/

Comment: Thanks for tips. Really I can't install nothing without installing it at production environment (and I can't do that), even if it's open source.